# Why when the same animation starts before the previous one finished the fade off does not work?

Tags: c#, wpf, fade, wpf-animation, coloranimation

I have the following simple animation:

```
<Window x:Class="AnimationTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel Background="Black">
        <TextBox Name="Box" >

        </TextBox>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=Box, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"  Foreground="White" >
            <TextBlock.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock"  >
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation AutoReverse="True" To="#A933FF" Duration="0:0:1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color" FillBehavior="Stop" IsCumulative="True" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBlock.Style>
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

It just makes flash a value when the value changes. if you write a letter you see it flash correctly to the color set in the animation and go back. But if you click several times the duration is longer (which is the desired behavior) but then it goes to the original color without fading out. Why does this happen and how to avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So once again, we have a question where a user provides some code and says *why is this happening?* The answer in this case is the normal answer to these questions:

> You wrote some code to *make* it happen

So to dig a little deeper, you have asked:

> if you write a letter you see it flash correctly to the color set in the animation and go back. But if you click several times the duration is longer (which is the desired behavior) but then it goes to the original color without fading out. Why does this happen and how to avoid it?

First, *why does this happen?*

So the reason why it is happening is because *you* declared a `ColorAnimation` that has no `From` value set, so it will always start from the current value, *whether this value has been manipulated by an `Animation` or not*:

```
<ColorAnimation AutoReverse="True" To="#A933FF" Duration="0:0:1" FillBehavior="Stop" 
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color" IsCumulative="True" />
```

For a single character entered, you'll see the `ColorAnimation` as you expected. However, when you continually type further characters, it will already have reached your set purple colour and you won't see any further animations until you stop typing, because it is now trying to animate from your purple colour to the same purple colour.

Now, *how to avoid it?*

To fix this issue, either supply a `From` colour, or set the `Duration` to be much quicker, or preferably both:

```
<ColorAnimation AutoReverse="True" From="White" To="#A933FF" Duration="0:0:0.1" 
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color" FillBehavior="Stop" 
    IsCumulative="True" />
```

Comment: So once again, we have an answer where a power user provides a good answer, so my response is the normal response to these answers: thanks!!!. Anyway I removed the From after a while the because I really don't know which color it will have at the beginning as it comes from a Dynamic resource and then you face the problem setting resources on the animations and freezables ... :S.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired result using `ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames` this will offer you much precise control over the same using keyframes instead of reversing the double animation which loses the initial value after being invoked multiple time and FillBehavior stop force it to revert to original value as result of animation complere

sample for you

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=Box, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"  Foreground="White" >
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color" >
                                <SplineColorKeyFrame Value="#A933FF"/>
                                <SplineColorKeyFrame Value="White" KeyTime="0:0:1"/>
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

more cleaner approach involves stopping the previous storyboard and invoking a new one

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=Box, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"  Foreground="White" >
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock"  >
            <Style.Resources>
                <Storyboard x:Key="animate">
                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" >
                        <SplineColorKeyFrame Value="#A933FF"/>
                        <SplineColorKeyFrame Value="White" KeyTime="0:0:1"/>
                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </Style.Resources>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="beginAnimate"/>
                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="beginAnimate" Storyboard="{StaticResource animate}"/>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```